# CSS selector: why `.classA + .classB:nth-of-type(3)` not working?

Tags: css, css-selectors

**Given HTML such:**

```
<div class="h2 colors">Title: Colors</div>
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>
```

**and CSS such**

```
.h2 + .pair:nth-of-type(2) { color: red; } /* works */
.h2 + .pair:nth-of-type(3) { color: green; } /* doesn't */
```

**Why the type(3) doesn't work ?**

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/HE2he/5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because type refers to element type, not class. In your case, since both `div.h2` and `div.pair` are of type `div`, they are all in the same sequence of elements by type:

```
<div class="h2 colors">Title: Colors</div> <!-- div:nth-of-type(1) -->
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>        <!-- div:nth-of-type(2) -->
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>        <!-- div:nth-of-type(3) -->
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>        <!-- div:nth-of-type(4) -->
<div class="pair">Hello world</div>        <!-- div:nth-of-type(5) -->
```

The adjacent sibling combinator `+` only looks at the sibling that comes immediately next. As shown above, `div.h2` here is the first `div`. Only the second `div`, not the third, can immediately follow the first, which is why your second rule doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[As @BoltClock said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565877), you are using adjacent sibling selector..

Instead change your rule to

```
div.pair:nth-of-type(2) { color: red; background: #C0C0C0; }
div.pair:nth-of-type(3) { color: green; background: #E0E0E0; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HE2he/6/)

These selectors will select the nth div element having a class of 'pair'